# How to format text for messages sent with the REST API?

Tags: circuit-sdk

Currently I am sending plain text messages, how can I format the text messages I send visibly within the conversation? Do I need to specify a different content-type or send rich or html format somehow within the REST API? e.g. I'd like to send line breaks (\r\n) or format responses as a list from the Bot.

If possible please provide a curl working example or something I can transfer to Postman. Thanks!

With the following REST API:
"https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations/ConversationID/messages"

Trying to send a message with a line break

content: Hello \r\n World" --or-- "content: "Hello CRLF World"

```
https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations/<ConversationID>/messages"

"accept", 'application/json'
"content-type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
"Authorization", "Bearer <Token>"
"content= Hello\r\nWorld"
```

**Expected:**
Hello
World

**Actual:**
Hello World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content should be HTML with a limited set of tags supported : strong, i, ul, ol, li and links.

For example : you can set content to :

```
This is a test<br> It can be <strong> formatted</strong> <i>a little</I>
```